# "en" vs "en-US" as default language for Windows 10 UWP (distributed worldwide)

Tags: localization, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm wondering what could be not obvious consequences from the user experience perspective if I'll choose to go with default language for UWP application as "**en**" instead of "**en-US**" and provide localized resources only for "**en**" culture, but not for "**en-US**".

Considering that there is not much text in the app I'm assuming that it should behave in English for, say, US-based users and Great Britain-based with equal experience, but just in case would like to be sure about that.

As far as I know if you leave the default language as "**en-US**" and provide resources for it the app will fallback to it for, say, "**en-GB** users", so that's where this question arose - what are the pros and cons to go with "**en**" or "**en-US**" for application, that is distributed worldwide?

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: @Alex It's been awhile, if the accepted answer is not working, then I'm not sure what would be solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as you do not differentiate `en` languages, there shouldn't be a difference if you choose `en-US`, `en` or `en-*`. As [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh967761.aspx):

> Windows prioritizes matching of languages in a standard well-understood way. For example, en-US matches, in priority order, en-US, en, en-GB, and so forth.
>
> • Windows does cross regional matching. For example, en-US matches en-US, then en, and then en-*.

Providing `en-US` and `en` would make sense if for example you have resources specific only for US, and other resources for the rest of `en` languages.

Comment: I defined **de-de** as Default-Language in my App Manifest (not en-US) so why does MS-Build want 'en-US'?
`1>MakePRI : warning 0xdef00522: Resources found for language(s) 'de-de,en,fr' but no resources found for default language(s): 'en-US'. Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language.`

Comment: @ndee Not, sure - ask new question on SO, maybe someone will know.

Comment: @ndee are you copying the appxmanifest in the build process? You might need to open the appxmanifest in XML editor and replace the `<Resource Language="x-generated" />` with `<Resource Language="de-de" />` and the other supported languages below. The topmost defined language is the default language.

Comment: @user1195883 I edited my manifest `...<Resources>
    <Resource Language="de-DE" />
    <Resource Language="en" />
    <Resource Language="fr" />
  </Resources>...` but still i get the error above (`...but no resources found for default language(s): 'en-US'...`) but 'en-US' is nowhere mentioned?

Comment: So if I use `en-GB` as my default language and resources (I'm a developer from the UK and I like my s'), I shouldn't encounter issues if people have their language set to `en-US` for example? I have a constant VS warning telling me to consider `en-US`

Comment: @MattBrewerton According to my knowledge there shouldn't be any problems with that, as the app doesn't find en-US or en, en-GB should be used instead. I'm not sure why you get the warning. If you want you can test it - run emulator with en-US and see how it works.